# invalid literal for int() with base 10 in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a profile page with an `<owner>` argument in the link the owner in the models is a `ForeignKey` to the user 
but with any value i submit it saids `invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

**models.py**

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name="user_profile_user_key",
        verbose_name="owner of the profile",
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )
```

**views.py**

```
def my_profile(request, owner):
    template='my_profile.html' 
    context = {
        'profile' : get_object_or_404(UserCommunityProfile, owner=owner),
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**TraceBack**

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\PycharmProjects\drop\community\views.py" in my_profile
  112.         'profile' : get_object_or_404(UserCommunityProfile, owner=owner),

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in get_object_or_404
  87.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  394.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  836.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  854.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1253.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1277.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1215.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_lookup
  1085.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
  18.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  115.                 self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "C:\Users\Raouf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  947.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /profiles/raouf
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'raouf'
```

**url**

```
path('profiles/<owner>', community_views.my_profile, name='profile'),
```

Comment: please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: just added it .

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory.  You can't convert `raouf` to an integer.  Did you define one of your models incorrectly?

Comment: but i am not trying to convert it to an int

Comment: something in your url mappings and/or template links is wrong... care to post your urls.py/template with link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`owner` field is ForeignKey which is stored as integer in DB by default. But you are trying to pass string value `raouf` as owner value to `get_object_or_404` method. You need to change lookup argument to `owner__username` if you want to get user by username:

```
get_object_or_404(UserCommunityProfile, owner__username=owner)
```